# Launch Xampp mac

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp, mamp

I have been trying to run xampp from the mac terminal; 
    "mysql -u root -p" //usually launches xampp
 results in the terminal echoing out an error. I'd love to know how to fix this as I just reinstalled xampp to /applications

i know theres an easy fix...