# How to run mysql commands from terminal on a MAMP install?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I just installed mamp (xampp) from the mamp.info page and it is working on my mac (both apache, php, phpmyadmin, and mysql). The only problem is when i try to run

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Which connects to mamp from the mac os terminal, i get a command error. I have installed and uninstalled mamp and xampp for mac multiple times to no avail.

I am following this tutorial; http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app and i can't get past a certain part because i don't want to use php admin, and i think it'd be cool to use it from the terminal.

My question; how do i configure mamp or xampp for mac to work from the terminal?

Comment: What error are you getting? It sounds like you just need to add the directory that contains `mysql` to your `PATH` environment variable. You do that in your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: ok how do i do that Barmar? I just reinstalled mamp, configured my ports and everything but when i type mysql -u root -p ; i get a 'command not found'

Comment: i'd like to know how to do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Xampp mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996016/launch-xampp-mac) and [How to run mysql commands from terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977425/how-to-run-mysql-commands-from-terminal)- please do not ask the same question multiple times. Instead edit and improve your question. Also take care to give a meaningful title to your question.

Comment: Your description is bad. Please append text of your error at least, and also what work have you done to fix it. Usually searching error text in Google is enough. The difference between Google and SO is that at SO answering your question takes time directly from users, so please use it as last resort, not first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this at the end of your `.bash_profile` script (create it if it doesn't already exist):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Comment: I appreciate that. I'm pretty sure i installed everything to applications I was browsing some other questions and saw you answered some other questions that pertain to this one. I'll copy and paste that code for sure but can you once again assist me in locating a '.bash_profile' script? Is this going to be in applications>mamp?

Comment: Also if its not there can you point me in the direction of creating a new one? thanks

Comment: It's in your home directory. Each user has their own `.bash_profile`, which is used to configure options when they start a Terminal session.

Comment: I think you need to read some tutorials on using the shell on Unix. I'm not going to try to teach you that here.

Comment: I finally found my .bash_profile script and added export PATH=$PATH:/directory/containing/mysql
Can you at least further explain 'Replace /directory/containing/mysql with the actual path of the directory where the mysql command was installed'?

Comment: It's plain English. That was just a placeholder, you're supposed to find the correct directory, and use that. E.g. if it's installed in `/opt/local/bin/mysql` then it should be `$PATH:/opt/local/bin/mysql`

Comment: its installed in my applications folder; would that simply be?;       export PATH=$PATH:/applications or /usr/local/bin something like this? I'm a noob here obviously...

Comment: Applications in `/Applications` are programs you can run by double-clicking from the Finder. They're not shell commands.

Comment: Ok, I've been looking for this snippet 48 hours. What does your 'export' line of code look like in your bash file. let me copy it

Comment: I don't have it in my file, I don't have MAMP on my machine. We use MySQL on Linux, not on our personal Macs.

Comment: you can just type "open -e .bash_profile" to open your bash in TextEdit

Comment: I found the path here: http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/08/using-mysql-command-line-with-mamp.html by googling _mamp where is mysql command installed_. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I copied and pasted that into the bash file but still no go.. i even tried saving .bash_profile to the bin lol

Comment: The profile is run when you open a Terminal window. Did you open a new window?